# How to select different data of the same table that depends on variable

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa

I need to select some data from a join table. The thing is that this table changes its data depending on a variable x (if x=1 the data is A and if x=2 the data is B)

I am trying something like this:

```
"SELECT new nameDTO(joinTableA.dataA, joinTableB.dataB, table.something, table....) "
              + "FROM Table table "
              + "JOIN joinTable joinTableA"
              + "JOIN joinTable joinTableB "
              + "WHERE joinTableA.x = 1 AND joinTableA.x = 2"
              + "AND ..... "
```

However this WHERE does not work because the query returns nothing instead of de data of both cases.

I hope the question in understandable, it's a bit tricky.

Comment: Print out the query.  As written, it is not going to run.  You should also be checking all the queries that you run for errors, such as syntax errors.

Comment: `joinTableA.x = 1 AND joinTableA.x = 2` gives always FALSE;
You can set `OR` to select both.

Comment: I can´t show the real sql query because of an Non Disclosure Agreement :S.

Comment: `I hope the question in understandable, it's a bit tricky.` You're right, your question si totally hazy.

Comment: The OR operator doesn't help because it also works when both are TRUE, i would need a XOR operator

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of information missing in your question, so I've made some up and hoping this is close enough to what you are trying to do.

I start with two tables. I'm only showing the content of the tables, not the definition.

table1

```
id    content
-------------
1     Hello
2     World
```

table2

```
table1_id    x   content_a   content_b
--------------------------------------
1            1   Content 1   Content 2
1            2   Content 3   Content 4
2            1   Content 5   Content 6
2            2   Content 7   Content 8
```

With the following SQL statement

```
SELECT
  t1.content `greeting`,
  CASE
    WHEN t2.x = 1 THEN t2.content_a
    WHEN t2.x = 2 THEN t2.content_b
    ELSE "Unknown x value"
  END `content`
FROM
  table1 `t1`
  INNER JOIN table2 `t2` ON t2.table1_id = t1.id
;
```

the result would be

```
greeting     content
----------------------
Hello        Content 1
Hello        Content 4
World        Content 5
World        Content 8
```

This should be possible to convert to a JPQL query or a Criteria query.